# How to remove a fragment from within itself

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

In my application, I have an instance of a fragment, `ActivityFragment`, which is added dynamically when a button, `addActivity`, is pressed. There is a `delete_button` in each `ActivityFragment`, and I have set an onClickListener for this button within the `ActivityFragment` class. When the `delete_button` is pressed, I want to remove the fragment from inside the onClick method. How would I go about doing this when I create the `ActivityFragment` object and add it to the activity in a method outside of the fragment class? And what field should I use for `.remove()`?

Note that `delete_button` should only remove the instance of the fragment it is in.

Here is my `MainActivity.java` with the `ActivityFragment` class. The `addActivity` button is at the bottom:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public static class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {
        // @Nullable is used because the method may return a null value
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View fragment1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);

            Button edit_button = (Button) fragment1.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
            Button delete_button = (Button) fragment1.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

            edit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView activityText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.activity_text);
                    activityText.setText("success");
                }
            });

            delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .remove().commit();
                }
            });

            return fragment1;
        }
    }

    public void addActivity(View view) {
        ActivityFragment myFragment = new ActivityFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the fragment instance like this

```
delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .remove(ActivityFragment.this).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of Android, so I'm not exactly sure what `ActivityFragment.this` is doing or how it works. Could you explain briefly or do you have any links to where I can read more on this? Thanks so much!

Comment: `ActivityFragment.this`gives you a reference of `ActivityFragment` object and you use this to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment can be removed by doing this:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.remove(myFragment).commit();
```

Here **myFragment** is your "FRAGMENT" that you want to remove from the current context or current activity.